# Upgraded to MacOS (Monterey) - AppleMail no longer toggles between open windows

Tags: mail.app

Apple Mail - cannot toggle between open windows (ex: All Inboxes; All Sent) using cmd`.  Worked fine before I updated to OS 12!

Comment: Command+` switches between *windows* and if you open two windows it will switch between them still in Monterey. You can use command+1-9 to switch between tabs in the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you Ezekiel but Command+` doesn't work.  I found Shift+Command+] will work but entirely non-intuitive.